# How to track opportunities that are born of other opportunities?

Tags: opportunity, history-tracking

I somewhat new to Salesforce and I want to be able to track Opportunities that are born from other opportunities.

We offer assessment services, where at the end of an assessment we can recommend other follow up engagements and sales, so being able to illustrate in a report or a dashboard revenue born of other assessments, and even to group it by assessment type would be our end goal.

Now I have quite a bit of development experience, and before I start to re-invent the wheel I want to be sure that I fully leverage Salesforce's built in capabilities.

I've read about using Campaigns to track opportunities, but is there a proper way to track opportunities born of other opportunities?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a specific feature per se which is used exclusively for such a use case, as the typical Sales process is Lead -> Contact -> Opportunity (which uses the standard lead conversion [process feature](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_convert.htm)).

However, there are many declarative ways to represent Opportunities born of other Opportunities. It depends really on what your business process(es) are. For example, you can use Record Types and Page Layouts to show different types of Opportunities (New Business, Renewals), you can use Lookup fields to link opportunities to other opportunities and other records.

You could even leverage Process Builder and custom fields to auto-create an opportunity whenever the original Assessment Service opportunity has expired and link it to the original. If your requirements are a bit more complicated, you can use custom code too.

P.S. there is currently an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Boy8AAC) to have a Salesforce feature specific to linking Opportunities to other Opportunities, instead of leveraging declarative features to build your own solution.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you for your response. I guess that a better way of putting might have been to link leads to existing opportunities. A lead that was born from an existing or closed opportunity. Would it still be the same scenario?

Comment: Hi Sonar, yes - you can link Leads to Opportunities via a custom lookup field. This link may be more helpful: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42212/what-happens-when-a-lead-is-converted.