# What is Lead conversion?

Tags: lead-conversion

I'm new to Salesforce. What should come to know first when I am entering into lead conversion.

Basically what it is and why we are using that in sfdc.
Give some ideas.

Comment: Go through this trailhead module https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/admin_intro_opptys_leads/admin_intro_opptys_leads_leads

Comment: What happens when a lead is converted http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42212/what-happens-when-a-lead-is-converted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, Salesforce is a CRM or Customer Relationship Manager. Accounts, Contacts, Leads, Opportunities, Products (etc...) are pretty common accross any CRM.

A lead is someone who might be interested in using your business' services. Maybe they've registered interest on your website or you've heard from a client that someone might be interested in your product.

The aim of any good sales person would be to convert a Lead to an Opportunity. In other words, get in touch with that Lead and start selling to them. If they don't dismiss you straight away and engage with you telling you what they need, asking about what you offer and how much you cost that'd really be an Opportunity.

The ultimate goal if an Opportunity is to make a sale in the end, get an Order in or a Contact signed.

In Salesforce there's different Objects, related to each other that define all this information. You can think of an object as a Spreadsheet in Excel.

For instance:

- A `Contact` might have details such as their `Name`, `Email` and `Phone`
- A `Lead` might have the related Contact and where the Lead came from (e.g. Website)
- If all goes well, you'd then convert that Lead to an `Opportunity`. That might include who the Related Contact, the Related Lead, the Probabability of Conversion, the Stages (i.e. your business process and standards)
- Finally, you'd ultimately end up with a sale

This is and isn't specific to Salesforce. I say it is because all of this is a part of Salesforce and I say it isn't because this is pretty general to any CRM.

If you want to learn, specifically about lead conversion: take this [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/admin_intro_opptys_leads/admin_intro_opptys_leads_leads). If you want to learn more about CRMs in general, have a look at [this one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/admin_intro_crm_basics). Finally, if you want to know about Salesforce specifically, [this is a nice one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/lex_implementation_basics).